# Overwrote the desktop folder to a file. How can i reverse it?

Tags: 17.10, directory, xsane

by erroneously executing xsane I overwrote my desktop folder with a pdf file.

How can I revert this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Just to clarify: I can still access my desktop from the launcher. I simply cannot add any files or folders to it anymore (and cannot open the desktop folder from my file manager)

[image: screenshot of desktop properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desktop configuration is stored in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. In your case the line with

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

is most likely wrong. So move the `Desktop` to somewhere else and create a new `Desktop` folder.

```
$ mv ~/Desktop ~/Desktop_backup.pdf
$ mkdir -p ~/Desktop
```

Logout and login again, you should be fine.

Comment: Based on his screenshot it seems that the PDF file is named `Desktop`, not `Desktop.pdf`.

Comment: @danzel thx, updated...